# Getting a Class Type to be a specific class

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class like

```
public class NewArrayList<T> extends ArrayList {
    // ...
}
```

And another class:

```
public class IntArrayList<T> extends NewArrayList<T> {
    /* something like throwing an exception if T is not Integer */
    // Integer-only methods
}
```

`IntArrayList<T>` is supposed to only accept `Integer` values. I have tried `T instanceof Integer` but it only errors. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
public class IntArrayList extends NewArrayList<Integer>
```

this binds the < T > and removes it for further subclasses.